# SWITCH function doesn't work in access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, ansi-sql, ansi-sql-92

With the code below, I'm trying to update table `K_tables`.  The column `ColumnType` doesn't have zero or null values in it, but after I run this script I get a lot of null valued rows, and the number of rows with certain values (such as `BIGINT`) is larger than expected.

```
 update K_tables set  ColumnType = Switch(
                ColumnType = 'I8' , 'BIGINT',
                ColumnType = 'I' , 'INTEGER',
                ColumnType = 'CF' , 'CHARACTER',
                ColumnType = 'D' , 'DECIMAL',
                ColumnType = 'I1' , 'BYTEINT',
                ColumnType = 'I2' , 'SMALLINT',
                ColumnType = 'DA' , 'DATE',
                ColumnType = 'TS' , 'TIMESTAMP',
                ColumnType = 'CV' , 'VARCHAR'

);
```

Is there something wrong with my query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are the results of this?

```
SELECT ColumnType, COUNT(*) FROM K_tables GROUP BY ColumnType
```

My guess is that there are values in there not mentioned in your SWITCH statement?  These will be forced to NULL as the SWITCH gave no result.

I would simply add a WHERE clause...

```
update
    K_tables
set
    ColumnType = Switch(
                     ColumnType = 'I8' , 'BIGINT',
                     ColumnType = 'I' , 'INTEGER',
                     ColumnType = 'CF' , 'CHARACTER',
                     ColumnType = 'D' , 'DECIMAL',
                     ColumnType = 'I1' , 'BYTEINT',
                     ColumnType = 'I2' , 'SMALLINT',
                     ColumnType = 'DA' , 'DATE',
                     ColumnType = 'TS' , 'TIMESTAMP',
                     ColumnType = 'CV' , 'VARCHAR'
                )
WHERE
    ColumnType IN ('I8','I', 'CF', 'D', 'I1', 'I2', 'DA', 'TS', 'CV')
;
```

This will mean that you only update rows that fit your criteria, and leave all the other rows alone.

Comment: I would also include a `count (*)` to the first `select - group by` because OP say a larger than expected number of `BIGINT` are appearing.

Comment: I dont know why, but adding `where in` row made query work as expected.